# R ggplot Line With Vertical Bands

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I wish to create a plot as the above with data such as this,

```
data1=data.frame("School"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
"Score"=c(80,64,79,64,64,89,69,71,61,98),
"ScoreLow"=c(65,62,62,60,60,84,54,55,55,69),
"ScoreHigh"=c(98,79,85,97,88,95,97,90,79,99))
```

The blue line is 'Score' and score is on the Y-AXIS and 'SChool' is on the X-AXIS. The length of the black line gets determined from 'ScoreLow' and 'ScoreHigh'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_errorbar` would also work, in case you want to add some ticks at the edges (or leave them out, setting `width=0`, as below):

```r
library(ggplot2)
data1=data.frame("School"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "Score"=c(80,64,79,64,64,89,69,71,61,98),
                 "ScoreLow"=c(65,62,62,60,60,84,54,55,55,69),
                 "ScoreHigh"=c(98,79,85,97,88,95,97,90,79,99))
ggplot(data1, aes(x=School, y=Score)) + geom_line(colour="#507bc7", size=2)+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ScoreLow, ymax=ScoreHigh), width=0, col="black", size=1.5) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a combination of `geom_line()` and `geom_segment()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = School, y = Score), color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = School, xend = School, y = ScoreLow, yend = ScoreHigh), size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = 0:10 * 10) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Need to probably play around a bit to get it how you want it.
[image: example plot]